# No longer want mypackage.app (pid 491): hidden #16

Tags: android, process

I fall into a strange issue. My app needs to start itself after user reboots the device. To accomplish this, I registered for action.BOOT_RECEIVER and implemented BroadcastReceiver to do the necessary functionality. I observe that every thing seems to be fine until this statement 
"I/ActivityManager(323): No longer want mypackage.app (pid 491): hidden #16".

I believe android wont launch two apps with different process ids.

When I launch the app, the app is starting with a new ProcessId, this leads to resetting of objects, but not the static variables. I wonder why the static variables are still retaining their values even after process is terminated.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/mH5dvnEMfzA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is resolved not sure what could be the reason. It is fixed now.